# Solving partial integro-differential equation with symmetry

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I want to solve below equation:

> $$ \partial_t u(\vec{\rho},t)=\nabla^2u - \nabla \cdot (u U) $$

where

$$ U = \int_a^L  \frac{u \vec{\rho}}{(\rho^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \rho d\rho d\phi$$

$\phi$ is angle between $\rho$ and $x$ axis. I tried to solve it using Laplace transform but as the problem is not linear in integral part, I failed to do that. How can I solve it? Is is a solveable or not? $\vec{\rho}$ is radial vector in polar coordinate.

Comment: Is this something from physics?

Comment: No, IT IS PURE MATHEMATICS @Dylan